# Android. Использование библиотеки RootTools.jar

Tags: java, android, root

Есть задача изменения прав доступа некоторого каталога на Android (устройство рутированное). Нашел библиотеку **RootTools.jar**. На их [гитхабе](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/wiki/Usage) описывается пример использования библиотеки:

```
RootTools.isRootAvailable()
Command command = new Command(0, "echo this is a command", "echo this is another command");
try {
    RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);
}catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Как правильно составить комманду, что бы установить для каталога *"data/data/"* и его файлов доступ 777 (чтение, запись, выполнение)? Спасибо.

Comment: Прям для всего каталого /data/data/ ? Это плохая идея. Но если очень надо, то можно "chmod -R 0777 /data/data"

Comment: @OlegA это да,но он же применяет команду только к каталогу data, а не к его файлам и папкам?

Comment: Ключ -R намекает на рекурствное изменение прав на все дочернии объекты